# While loop leads to `Missing number, treated to zero` with latex3

Tags: pdftex, expl3, loops

I am trying to learn latex3 to write more powerful LaTeX functions.
For that I am implementing a `timesum` variable that contains the time in minutes. You can add to that sum either hours days or minutes. That works great.

Now I try to output `timesum` split into days hours and minutes.

However, not even finding out the full days in the sum works and instead breaks with `Missing number, treated as zero`.

I do not understand why...

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultsans, scale=0.9]{opensans}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new:N \timesum

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtime}{O{\timesum}mm}
{
    \str_case_e:nnF { #3 } { 
        {h}{\fp_add:Nn #1 {\fp_eval:n {#2 * 60}}}
        {d}{\fp_add:Nn #1 {\fp_eval:n {#2 * 60 * 24}}}
    }
    { \fp_add:Nn #1 {#2} } % default
    #2\,#3
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showtimesum}{O{\timesum}m}{
    \str_case_e:nnF { #2 } { 
        {h}{\fp_eval:n { #1 / 60}\,h}
        {d}{\fp_eval:n {#1 / 60 / 24}\,d}
        {min}{\fp_use:N  #1 \,min}
    }
    { \fp_use:N #1 \,min} % default
}

%\int_incr:N

\NewDocumentCommand{\strtime}{O{\timesum}}{
    \fp_new:N \l_fp_tmp_timemin             % new var
    \fp_set_eq:NN \l_fp_tmp_timemin #1      % set var to value of #1
    %\fp_use:N \l_fp_tmp_timemin                % print var
    
    % find out days iteratively
    \int_do_while:nNnn {\l_fp_tmp_timemin} {>} {1439.999} {
        \fp_sub:Nn \l_fp_tmp_timemin {1440}
        %\fp_use:N \l_fp_tmp_timemin
    }
    
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{recipient}
        \opening{opening}

        \addtime{20.5}{h}
        \addtime{30}{min}
        \addtime{2.7}{d}
        
        \showtimesum{h}
        \strtime
        
        %\showsum
        \closing{concluding text}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: decide if you want floating numbers or integers, don't use \int_do_while on a floating point variable. And don't use \fp_new inside a command, if you call the command twice you will get error. Check also the naming conventions, \l_fp_tmp_timemin is wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for the hints. Although I know a few programming languages the expl3 syntax is still strange to me. Using `\fp_do_while` indeed works... `\l_tmpa_fp` seems to be correct but fails for being already defined... would `\l_tmp_timemin_fp` be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly store the time sum in minutes in an `fp` variable,
but for printing the total time, you want to round to an integer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newtime}{m}
 {
  \fp_new:c { l_mrcarnivore_time_#1_fp }
 }
\newtime{default} % initialize one

% \addtime* will also show the added time
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtime}{sO{default}mm}
 {
  \mrcarnivore_time_add:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
  % with \addtime* also show what's been added
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{#3\,\textup{#4}}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\strtime}{O{default}}
 {
  \mrcarnivore_time_str:n { #1 }
 }

\int_new:N \l__mrcarnivore_time_days_int
\int_new:N \l__mrcarnivore_time_hours_int
\int_new:N \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mrcarnivore_time_add:nnn
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #3 }
   {
    {h}{ \fp_add:cn { l_mrcarnivore_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 } }
    {d}{ \fp_add:cn { l_mrcarnivore_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 * 24 } }
    {min}{ \fp_add:cn { l_mrcarnivore_time_#1_fp } { #2 } }
   }
   {\ERROR}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mrcarnivore_time_str:n
 {
  % round to an integral number of minutes
  \int_set:Nn \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int
   {
    \fp_eval:n { round( \fp_use:c { l_mrcarnivore_time_#1_fp }, 0 ) }
   }
  % compute the number of days
  \int_set:Nn \l__mrcarnivore_time_days_int
   {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int } { 1440 }
   }
  % remove the days
  \int_set:Nn \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int
   {
    \int_mod:nn { \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int } { 1440 }
   }
  % compute the number of hours
  \int_set:Nn \l__mrcarnivore_time_hours_int
   {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int } { 60 }
   }
  % remove the hours
  \int_set:Nn \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int
   {
    \int_mod:nn { \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int } { 60 }
   }
  % now print the days
  \int_compare:nT { \l__mrcarnivore_time_days_int > 0 }
   {
    \int_eval:n { \l__mrcarnivore_time_days_int }\,\textup{d}\;
   }
  % now print the hours
  \int_compare:nTF { \l__mrcarnivore_time_hours_int > 0 }
   {
    \int_eval:n { \l__mrcarnivore_time_hours_int }\,\textup{h}
   }
   {% no hours
    \unkern
   }
  \;
  % now print the minutes
  \int_compare:nTF { \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int > 0 }
   {
    \int_eval:n { \l__mrcarnivore_time_minutes_int }\,\textup{min}
   }
   {% no minutes
    \unkern
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addtime{20.5}{h}

\strtime

\addtime{30}{min}

\strtime

\addtime{2.7}{d}
        
\strtime

\end{document}
```

[image]

What does `\unkern` do? Suppose the final answer should be “two days and eight minutes”.

The code will add a thin space `\,` between 2 and d, and also a med space `\;` after it. What happens is that if there are no hours to show, this med space would stay and accumulate with the med space issued after hours. Similarly when there are zero minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had looked for modulo but was not able to find it. Maybe because as I found out now it is mentioned as `remainder` in the documentation. Just before you posted I also had the idea that I do not have to calculate this iteratively. However, your solution is even more elegant than what I had in mind. I learned a lot from your example but still have some questions: What does the argument `s` do for `\NewDocumentCommand`? And what is the advantage of using `\cs_new_protected`? And what does `\unkern` do?

Comment: And what do you think of my new function that combines mod and div: `\NewDocumentCommand{\int_div_mod:nnn}{mmm}{
  \int_set:Nn #3 
   { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
  
  \int_set:Nn #1
   { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
  }`

Comment: Ok, I found out the `s` is for the star version and also know how `\cs_new_protected` works. But what really is the advantage especially for `\mrcarnivore_time_add:nnn`? It is not re-used... About the function of `\unkern` I am still unclear. Also why did you not add the same `{ \unkern }` for no days? I have tried adding this (of course with changing the command before  to `\int_compare:nTF` but then it breaks... strange... Also `\addtime*{20.5}{h}` does not show the `h` although `#3` is used...

Comment: @mrCarnivore I added some explanation about the logic for `\unkern` (and fixed the code).

Comment: Thanks for the code fix. I guessed about the same with `\unkern`. However, removing it changed nothing (of course with an example with no hours). Also why is there not `\unkern` with the days? And why does it crash when I add it (with adapting the function for day to `\int_compare:nTF` of course?