# Summing does not work in longtable

Tags: pdftex, longtable, latex3

I had used a sum with `\newcounter` and `\addtocounter` in a longtable and everything worked fine but the usage was a little complicated.

With egreg's help I was able to create a latex3 version to create a sum of different time units and then display the result in a understandable form: [earlier question that was answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684289/while-loop-leads-to-missing-number-treated-to-zero-with-latex3?noredirect=1#comment1697809_684289)

Everything works fine, but when I tried to use it in a longtable the sum gets reset every line. Why is that and how I prevent that?

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrlttr2}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultsans, scale=0.9]{opensans}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newtime}{m}
{
    \fp_new:c { l_timecalc_time_#1_fp }
}
\newtime{default} % initialize one

% \addtime* will also show the added time
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtime}{sO{default}mm}
{
    \timecalc_time_add:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }

    % with \addtime* also show what's been added    
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{#3\,\textup{#4}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\strtime}{O{default}}
{
    \timecalc_time_str:n { #1 }
}

\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_days_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_hours_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_add:nnn
{
    \str_case:nnF { #3 }
    {
        {h}{ \fp_add:cn { l_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 } }
        {d}{ \fp_add:cn { l_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 * 24 } }
        {min}{ \fp_add:cn { l_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 } }
    }
    {\ERROR}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \int_div_mod:nnn {
    \int_set:Nn #3 
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    
    \int_set:Nn #1
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_str:n
{
    % round to an integral number of minutes
    \int_set:Nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int
        { \fp_eval:n { round( \fp_use:c { l_timecalc_time_#1_fp }, 0 ) } }
        
    % compute and remove the number of days
    \int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{1440}{\l__timecalc_time_days_int}
    
    % compute and remove the number of hours
    \int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{60}{\l__timecalc_time_hours_int}
    
    % now print the days
    \int_compare:nT { \l__timecalc_time_days_int > 0 }
        { \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_days_int }\,\textup{d}\; }

    % now print the hours
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int > 0 }
    {
        \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int }\,\textup{h}\;
    }
    {% no hours
        %\unkern
    }
    % now print the minutes
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int > 0 }
    {
        \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int }\,\textup{min}
    }
    {% no minutes
        %\unkern
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{longtable}[=v4.13]
\usepackage{tabu}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{recipient}
    \opening{opening}
    
    \begin{longtable}{c}
        \textbf{time}
        \endhead
        \addtime*{20.5}{h}\\
        \addtime*{30}{min}\\
        \addtime*{2.7}{d}\\
    \end{longtable}
    
    This leads to a complete time of \strtime.
    
    Normal sum:
    
    \addtime*{20.5}{h}
    
    \addtime*{30}{min}
    
    \addtime*{2.7}{d}
    
    This leads to a complete time of \strtime.
        
    \closing{concluding text}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: Also `\unkern` breaks the in longtable and therefore had to be uncommented.

Comment: you are using local assignments, and table cells are groups

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: How can I use global assignments and keep the `l_timecalc_time_#1_fp` outside the groups to access it afterwards?

Comment: you need `g_`  variables not `l_`  and eg  `\int_gset` not `\int_set`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I thought the `l_ ` was just for the user and has no real effect in the program... but using `\int_gset` maybe is enough...

Comment: if you turn on expl3 checking you will get errors for mis-named variables. There is no point using a naming convention and then ignoring it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I agree that you have to follow conventions. I was just confused that not following the convention made my program not work. How can I turn on expl3 checking with TeXstudio?

Comment: it would (by default) work with an l_ variable  but would be bad form.  `\usepackage[check-declarations][expl3}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the help from David Carlisle I was able to make it work with using `g_` for the variable storing the sum and using `\fp_gadd` instead of `\fp_add` for adding to the sum:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrlttr2}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultsans, scale=0.9]{opensans}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newtime}{m}
{
    \fp_new:c { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp }
}
\newtime{default} % initialize one

% \addtime* will also show the added time
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtime}{sO{default}mm}
{
    \timecalc_time_add:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }

    % with \addtime* also show what's been added    
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{#3\,\textup{#4}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\strtime}{O{default}}
{
    \timecalc_time_str:n { #1 }
}

\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_days_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_hours_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_add:nnn
{
    \str_case:nnF { #3 }
    {
        {h}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 } } % <= using \fp_gadd
        {d}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 * 24 } } % <= using \fp_gadd
        {min}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 } } % <= using \fp_gadd
    }
    {\ERROR}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \int_div_mod:nnn {
    \int_set:Nn #3 
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    
    \int_set:Nn #1
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_str:n
{
    % round to an integral number of minutes
    \int_set:Nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int
        { \fp_eval:n { round( \fp_use:c { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp }, 0 ) } }
        
    % compute and remove the number of days
    \int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{1440}{\l__timecalc_time_days_int}
    
    % compute and remove the number of hours
    \int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{60}{\l__timecalc_time_hours_int}
    
    % now print the days
    \int_compare:nT { \l__timecalc_time_days_int > 0 }
        { \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_days_int }\,\textup{d}\; }

    % now print the hours
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int > 0 }
    {
        \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int }\,\textup{h}\;
    }
    {% no hours
        %\unkern
    }
    % now print the minutes
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int > 0 }
    {
        \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int }\,\textup{min}
    }
    {% no minutes
        %\unkern
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{longtable}[=v4.13]
\usepackage{tabu}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{recipient}
    \opening{opening}
    
    \begin{longtable}{c}
        \textbf{time}
        \endhead
        \addtime*{20.5}{h}\\
        \addtime*{30}{min}\\
        \addtime*{2.7}{d}\\
    \end{longtable}
    
    This leads to a complete time of \strtime.
    
    Normal sum:
    
    \addtime*{20.5}{h}
    
    \addtime*{30}{min}
    
    \addtime*{2.7}{d}
    
    This leads to a complete time of \strtime.
        
    \closing{concluding text}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
  function addtime(value, unit)
    if unit == "d" then 
      value = value * 24 * 60 
    elseif unit == "h" then 
      value = value * 60 
    end
    return value 
  end
  function gettime(name)
    days = name//1440
    name = name - days * 1440
    hours = name//60
    minutes = math.floor(name - hours * 60)
    return (tostring(days).."\\,d, "..tostring(hours).."\\,h, "..tostring(minutes).."\\,min")    
  end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand*\settime[1][default]{\directlua{ #1 = 0 }}
\settime

\newcommand*\addtime[3][default]{%
    #2 #3
    \directlua{ #1 = #1 + addtime(#2,"#3") }}

\newcommand*\gettime[1][default]{%
    \directlua{ tex.print( gettime(#1)) }}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
        
        \begin{longtable}{c}
            \textbf{time}
            \endhead
            \addtime{20.5}{h}\\
            \addtime{30}{min}\\
            \addtime{2.7}{d}\\
        \end{longtable}
        
        This leads to a complete time of \gettime.
        
        Normal sum:
        
        \addtime{20.5}{h}
        
        \addtime{30}{min}
        
        \addtime{2.7}{d}
        
        This leads to a complete time of \gettime.
        
\end{document}
```